# NDSolve precision for non-linear ODE with variable initial conditions

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to numerically solve a non-linear ODE with variable initial conditions, specifically it is :

$$ \partial_{t}R (r,t) ^2 + 2 R(r,t) \partial_{t} ^2 R(r,t) +r^2 k(r) = 0 $$
and my initial conditions are 
$$ R(r,1) = r (1-\frac{r}{10})^{2/3} \ \ \ \partial_{t} R(r,1) = \frac{2}{3} \frac{r}{(1-\frac{r}{10})^{1/3}}.$$

Here $t >1 $ and $0\leq r \leq 1$ and $k(r) = \frac{(1-(r^2-1-10^{-4})^{20}}{r^2}. $

I solve this equation two ways :

1) By treating $R$ as a function of $t$ alone, and defining a solution function using NDSolve:

```
sol[r_]:= NDSolve[{R'[t]^2+ 2 R[t] R''[t]==-r^2 k[r], R[1]== r(1-r/10)^2/3, 
    R'[1]==(2/3) 4/(1-r/10)^(1/3)},R,{t,1,3}, WorkingPrecision-> 50,
    AccuracyGoal->40, PrecisionGoal->40, InterpolationOrder->All]
```

Then I can just compute $sol[r][t]$ which is really $R[r,t]$ for any $r$. When I plot the left hand side of the differential equation for any $r$, by setting the WorkingPrecision to around 20 I exactly get zero, as I should. 
The disadvantage here is that I cannot treat $sol[r][t]$ as a function of $r$. I cannot differentiate it with respect to $r$, or at least I don't know how.

2) I solve it using

```
sol= NDSolve[{D[R[r,t],t]^2 + 2 R[r,t] D[R[r,t],{t,2}]==-r^2 k[r], R[r,1]== r(1-r/10)^2/3,
    Derivative[0,1][R][r,1]==(2/3) 4/(1-r/10)^(1/3)},R,{t,1,3}, {r,9/10,1}, 
    WorkingPrecision-> 50, AccuracyGoal->40, PrecisionGoal->40, InterpolationOrder->All]
```

Then I am in trouble because when I evaluate the left hand side using the
numerical solution I do not get zero for all values of $r$.

I think something gets screwed up as it multiplies interpolating functions 
together, but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Try using `ParametricNDSolve`,with `r` as the parameter.  According to the documentation, it is possible to differentiate with respect to the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

```
k[r] = (1 - (r^2 - 1 - 10^-4)^20)/r^2
```

Use

```
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{R'[t]^2 + 2 R[t] R''[t] == -r^2 k[r], 
   R[1] == r (1 - r/10)^2/3, R'[1] == (2/3) 4/(1 - r/10)^(1/3)}, 
   R, {t, 1, 3}, {r}];
dsol = Derivative[1][sol]
```

and then plot, for example, `R[1][t]`, `R'[1][t]`, and (to verify that this really is the derivative with respect to `r`), `(R[1.1]-R[1])/.1`.

```
Plot[{sol[1][t], dsol[1][t], (sol[1.1][t] - sol[1.0][t])/.1}, {t, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

A 3D plot shows that the function is smooth except as `r` approaches `0`.

```
Plot3D[sol[r][t], {t, 1, 3}, {r, 0.006, 1}, AxesLabel -> {t, r, R}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, 12]]
```

[image]